# Passing Javascript Variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables, var

I am trying to pass a variable to a php, I have tried the code below, but it was not working. Note: that the code below is just an example of what I am working on. I just made it that simple.

```
<script>
  var value = 0;
  alert("<?php echo"+value +" ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible. Javascript is client (browser) based, and php is server based.

Comment: Please post comments as comments not as answers

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var value = 0;
  window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?value=" + value;
</script>
```

Replace `myphpfile.php` with your filename, then you can use the `$_GET['value']` in your PHP code to display the variable.

e.g.

```
<?php
echo($_GET['value']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-sided scripting language. The PHP script runs when your page loads so its impossible to put a Javascript variable in your page after the code ran. It might be possible when you post your Javascript variable in a form. You can also try posting it using jQuery without a page refresh.